# Mapping reference 'myMappingName' of type 'mappingReference' in database 'myDatabaseName' could not be found. (In ADX)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

Upon ingestion, a failure is always reported regarding a missing mapping reference. This mapping reference however never existed, nor is it used anywhere. Ingestion however always goes through fine, and all data is present. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have looked into the logs to see the full reason, and the cause is that it can't find a certain mapping reference. This reference isn't used anywhere and was never created (to the best of my knowledge). Going through all the ingestion mappings on the cluster didn't give any information as to the reason why.

A bit more info on the log:

```
"OriginatesFromUpdatePolicy": false,
"ErrorCode": BadRequest_MappingReferenceWasNotFound,
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for getting Error:**

If we did not provide proper Database(onkdb) & Column Data Then we get an Mapping error shown Below.

[image]

**Resolution for this issue:**

Now I have provided Existing Database name(onkdb2) & Column data, Now I am getting Mapping data Below.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The problem we are facing is that the ingestion mapping that is trying to be referenced was never created as it was never intended to be made. ADX is now trying to find it, however it shouldn't ever be called upon. We use a differently named ingestion napping that is just the same name but with an "s" (plural). I am trying to find a way to, effectively, stop ADX from trying to use that mapping at all, as it just simply isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wanted to know how we are dealing with the problem, currently we have created a mapping that creates empty rows (thus silencing the error). These rows are not mapped out of the source table, so do not affect the child tables.